# Azure AKS - I disabled addon-http-application-routing but pods, deployments, services and stuff is till in the cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service, azure-aks

I have a brand new kubernetes cluster on AKS.

I disabled the addons with the azure-cli as described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing#remove-http-routing):

```
az aks disable-addons --addons http_application_routing --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup --no-wait
```

The portal shows no domain associated to the cluster.

But with kubelets I still see all the pods and deployments related to the addon.

I tried to delete deployments and stuff with kubectl, but the deployments recreates themself.

Have anybody experienced the same?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of aks you are using? there is a known issue with 1.12.6. https://github.com/Azure/AKS/releases

Comment: I have kubernetes version 1.12.6. Should this means that I'm experiencing this known issue?

Comment: well, unless you have a better explanation, i'd stick with that one, since its a known issue with 1.12.6

Answer (score 2):

there is a known issue with 1.12.6

```
Unable to disable addons on deployed clusters
AKS Engineering is diagnosing an issue around existing/deployed clusters being unable to disable Kubernetes addons within the addon-manager. When we have identified and repaired the issue we will roll out the required hot fix to all regions.
This impacts all addons including monitoring, http application routing, etc.
```

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/releases